# How to Truncate a huge mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, truncate

I have a table with 130824 records. Its Storage Engine is MyISAM. I want to truncate it. When I execute command on SSH, PHP script or phpmyadmin they show loading for long time but nothing happened. I have tried following commands one by one in SSH, phpmyadmin and even via PHP.

```
1. TRUNCATE TABLE `table_name` ;
2. TRUNCATE `table_name` ;
3. DELETE FROM `table_name` ;
4. DELETE FROM `table_name` LIMIT 100 ; // even this also halt the system in loading condition
```

Please guide me the best way to solve this.

Comment: Since these commands normally work you have to go into detail. Othrwise we just have to guess why the default behaviour is not working.

Comment: Yeah its also strange for me. Also i am not getting any error or warning.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
MYSQL_CONNECT('host','database_username','database_password');
@mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

$query="TRUNCATE table_name";

mysql_query($query);
mysql_close()
?>
```

Try this php script to truncate a specific table.